# Apache2 too many requests "waiting for connection"

Tags: server, apache2, performance

I've got `Apache 2.4` installed on a ubuntu based server with the `event` mpm module which seems to have too many idle processes Most of them are waiting for connection and a fraction of those requests are being processed at a time here is what server status reports this seems like a bottle neck and possible reason for increased `TTFB`. I am not a server guy trying to understand what could be the possible cause for this.

```
Server load: 0.31 0.31 0.34    
CPU Usage: u18750.3 s2242.49 cu0 cs0 - .372% CPU load
5.26 requests/sec - 432.6 kB/second - 82.2 kB/request
1 requests currently being processed, 249 idle workers

________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
________________________________________________________________
___________________________W__
```

Comment: When using the MPM module there will be a bunch of idle connections created in a pool in order to handle requests more quickly than a listen⇢init⇢process⇢respond cycle would take. Are you seeing actual system issues? Or are you simply unsure of why there are (currently) 250 mostly-idle connections?

Comment: Hi @matigo Thanks for you for your response i am simply unsure of why there are (currently) 250 mostly-idle connections while number of requests are too high. I assumed that number of requests should directly be linked to number of busy threads.

Comment: How do you know the number of requests are too high? From the data in your question, which shows one active process, I’d say the requests are minimal 

Comment: @matigo as mentioned in question request rate on server is 5.26 requests/sec

Comment: Your question @installed on a ubuntu based server@ what version of Ubuntu are you using?